# Are there any Triple Parity RAID cards commercially avaliable?

Tags: raid

I am looking to setup a triple parity raid system.  I was searching for a hardware triple parity RAID card to use with a SAS expander from the usual suspects, but could not find any.  Are there any commercially available triple parity cards on the market right now?  If not, are there any to be made available in the near future?

Comment: would RAID 60 not be three levels of parity?

Comment: Something like ZFS RAIDZ3 in hardware form?

Comment: @SpacemanSpiff He's talking about a parity array with 3 parity disks, like I guess what would be RAID 7, if they chose to continue the numbering in that fashion. (RADI5: 1 parity disk, RAID6: 2 parity disks, RAID7: 3 parity disks...)

Comment: Yes, something like Hardware RaidZ3 is what I am looking for.  I've also seen it referred to as "RAID 7.3" i.e. parity raid with 3 parity disks.  RAID60 does allow 3 disk failures before the array is potentially destroyed but I'm looking for actual triple parity RAID.  I suspect the characteristics of RAID60 is why these might not exist.

Comment: How large on an array are we talking and what type of disks? It seems like 3 parity disks would be excessive in most cases and write performance would be abysmal. I hope you've got a *lot* of write cache.

Comment: @Chuu were you able to find one? Am searching for it right now, but still cannot find any ..

Comment: @andreas-h No, however 3 years later software defined storage solutions have gotten so good that I am not particularly interested in any hardware RAID solutions anymore.